# Convert Object structure to different format using function

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects like so:

```
 const questions = [
    {
    "id":1,    
    "question":"What animal does bacon come from?",
    "correctAnswer": "A",
    "A":"pig",
    "B":"cow",
    "C":"sheep"
    },
   {
    "id":2,
    "question":"Which planet is closest to the sun?",
    "correctAnswer": "B",
    "A":"Saturn",
    "B":"Mercury",
    "C":"Venus"
   }

];
```

I want to convert it into the following format:

```
var newQuestionStructure = {
id: 1,
question:{ Voice: "what animal does bacon come from?", Display:"what animal does bacon come from?"},
correctAnswer:"A",
answers:
{
  A:
  {
    Voice: "pig" , 
    Display:"pig" ,
    Letter:"A"
  },
  B:
  {
    Voice: "cow" , 
    Display:"cow" ,
    Letter:"B"
  },
  C:
  {
    Voice: "sheep" , 
    Display:"sheep" ,
    Letter:"C"
  },
}
}
```

I wrote the following function as an attempt to create a new array of objects with my new desired structure:

```
var QuestionJson = require('./output');
var newQuestionArray =[];

for (let x=0;x<QuestionJson.length;x++){
newQuestionArray.push({
id: QuestionJson[x].id,
question: { Voice:QuestionJson[x].A, Display:QuestionJson[x].question},
correctAnswer:QuestionJson[x].correctAnswer,
answers:
{
  A:
  {
    Voice: QuestionJson[x].A , 
    Display:QuestionJson[x].A ,
    Letter:"A"
  },
  B:
  {
    Voice: QuestionJson[x].B , 
    Display:QuestionJson[x].B ,
    Letter:"B"
  },
  C:
  {
    Voice: QuestionJson[x].C , 
    Display:QuestionJson[x].C ,
    Letter:"C"
  },
}
}
);
}
```

However, the output of this function produces [Object] values for some of the keys:

```
[ { id: 1,
    question:
     { Voice: 'What animal does bacon come from?',
       Display: 'What animal does bacon come from?' },
    correctAnswer: 'A',
    answers: { A: [Object], B: [Object], C: [Object] } },
  { id: 2,
    question:
     { Voice: 'Which planet is closest to the sun?',
       Display: 'Which planet is closest to the sun?' },
    correctAnswer: 'B',
    answers: { A: [Object], B: [Object], C: [Object] } } ]
```

What is causing this issue? I noticed that the "question" key and its sub object display fine - but on my "answers" key I see this [Object] value instead of my object!

Any help would be great cheers!

```js
var QuestionJson = [{
    "id": 1,
    "question": "What animal does bacon come from?",
    "correctAnswer": "A",
    "A": "pig",
    "B": "cow",
    "C": "sheep"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "question": "Which planet is closest to the sun?",
    "correctAnswer": "B",
    "A": "Saturn",
    "B": "Mercury",
    "C": "Venus"
  }

];

var newQuestionArray = [];

for (let x = 0; x < QuestionJson.length; x++) {
  newQuestionArray.push({
    id: QuestionJson[x].id,
    question: {
      Voice: QuestionJson[x].A,
      Display: QuestionJson[x].question
    },
    correctAnswer: QuestionJson[x].correctAnswer,
    answers: {
      A: {
        Voice: QuestionJson[x].A,
        Display: QuestionJson[x].A,
        Letter: "A"
      },
      B: {
        Voice: QuestionJson[x].B,
        Display: QuestionJson[x].B,
        Letter: "B"
      },
      C: {
        Voice: QuestionJson[x].C,
        Display: QuestionJson[x].C,
        Letter: "C"
      },
    }
  });
}

console.log(newQuestionArray)
```

Comment: your code works fine ...

Comment: Ah, so maybe something isnt configured correctly in my terminal?! - I'd like to be able to copy and paste the output of this function so I can save it.

Comment: You can use ```console.log (JSON.stringify (newQuestionArray, null, 2);``` to print it pretty

Comment: brilliant thanks! what are these additional parameters in this json stringify function representing?

Comment: See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

The function worked fine. The problem was with the output in my terminal.

Flappix demonstrated By using the JSON stringify function along with some optional parameters, the object printed fine in the terminal.

[json stringify ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
console.log (JSON.stringify (newQuestionArray, null, 2);
```

Comment: if you want to save the output directly to a file (and you're on linux) you could redirect stdout into a file like this: `node index.js > data.json`